# How to disable top left arrow '<-' on Android Wi-Fi settings screen?

Tags: android, wifi, settings

I open the WiFi settings page from my Android application with:

*startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));*

Here I want to disable the left arrow at the top of the WiFi settings to avoid, that the user could enter all the other settings. It would be even better if the arrow could be used to finish the settings page.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry it is not possible. You can not disable Os back events. If you really want to do that Try to create your own WIFI chooser screen inside your application.

Comment: Thanks, so I could stop the search for that issue. Do you know an example project for customized Wi-Fi settings?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you need:

startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

On my Xiaomi phone there is back navigation button in WIFI settings but that opens your application again not all settings menu.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this activity doesn't help me here. It seems that every mobile company creates its own settings user interface.

Comment: Of course !!When a software is opened sourse even me or you can modify it!!

Comment: But this code works everytime...I used it once or twice on my projects!!How does not work at your android?? Sorry for my broken English!!

Comment: I always could reach all other settings from the called Wi-Fi page. That shall be not allowed. I only want to allow the user to change Wi-Fi settings.   This requirement is for a homescreen app.